# UISearchDisplayController table frame

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have `UISearchDisplayController` in my `UIViewController` and when i press the searchbar and search for something it's look like this:

[image]

[image]

As you can see it's have more 44 px . Any idea what can be the issue?

Comment: Have you tried setting your searchDisplayController tableview's frame in this method ---> -(void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if height of your searchResultsTableView is the problem, you can do something like this,

```
-(void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    CGRect frm = self._table.frame;
    CGRect searchfrm = self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.frame;
    searchfrm.size.height = frm.size.height;
    tableView.frame = searchfrm;
}
```

Here self._table is my tableView and I wanted the height of my searchResultsTableView to be same as of self._table.
Method I have used is delegate method of searchdisplaycontroller.
Hope it might solve your problem.